# Edit within multi-line sed match

Tags: regex, perl, replace, sed

I have a very large file, containing the following blocks of lines throughout:

```
start :234
modify 123 directory1/directory2/file.txt
delete directory3/file2.txt
modify 899 directory4/file3.txt
```

Each block starts with the pattern "start : #" and ends with a blank line. Within the block, every line starts with "modify # " or "delete ".

I need to modify the path in each line, specifically appending a directory to the front. I would just use a general regex to cover the entire file for "modify #" or "delete ", but due to the enormous amount of other data in that file, there will likely be other matches to this somewhat vague pattern. So I need to use multi-line matching to find the entire block, and then perform edits within that block. This will likely result in >10,000 modifications in a single pass, so I'm also trying to keep the execution down to less than 30 minutes.

My current attempt is a sed one-liner:

```
sed '/^start :[0-9]\+$/ { :a /^[modify|delete] .*$/ { N; ba }; s/modify [0-9]\+ /&Appended_DIR\//g; s/delete /&Appended_DIR\//g }' file_to_edit
```

Which is intended to find the "start" line, loop while the lines either start with a "modify" or a "delete," and then apply the sed replacements.

However, when I execute this command, no changes are made, and the output is the same as the original file.

Is there an issue with the command I have formed? Would this be easier/more efficient to do in perl? Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I will clarify where I can.

Comment: Why do you care about blocks? If it is possible to target all lines that starts with "modify" or "delete" you will obtain good performances. If you are looking for performances, if think sed will be better than perl. But I suspect an awk way to be faster.

Comment: With the simplicity of the "delete" pattern, and the thousands of lines of source code scattered throughout the rest of the file, there is at least some chance that another line will start with the same pattern, not within one of these blocks.

Comment: ok, so the main reason is that the file may contain other lines that starts with "delete" in particular or "modify" that are outside blocks and you want to preserve?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes, exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be better off with `perl`

Specifically because you can work 'per record' by setting `$/` - if you're records are delimited by blank lines, setting it to `\n\n`.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = "\n\n";
while (<>) {

    #multi-lines of text one at a time here.
    if (m/^start :\d+/) {
        s/(modify \d+)/$1 Appended_DIR\//g;
        s/(delete) /$1 Appended_DIR\//g;
    }
    print;
}
```

Each iteration of the loop will pick out a blank line delimited chunk, check if it starts with a pattern, and *if* it does, apply some transforms.

It'll take data from `STDIN` via a pipe, or `myscript.pl somefile`.

Output is to `STDOUT` and you can redirect that in the normal way.

Your limiting factor on processing files in this way are typically:

- Data transfer from disk
- pattern complexity

The more complex a pattern, and especially if it has variable matching going on, the more backtracking the regex engine has to do, which can get expensive. Your transforms are simple, so packaging them doesn't make very much difference, and your limiting factor will be likely disk IO.

(If you want to do an in place edit, you can with this approach)

If - as noted - you can't rely on a record separator, then what you can use instead is `perl`s [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) (other answers already do this, I'm just expanding it out a bit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {

    if ( /^start :/ .. /^$/)
        s/(modify \d+)/$1 Appended_DIR\//g;
        s/(delete) /$1 Appended_DIR\//g;
    }
    print;
}
```

We don't change `$/` any more, and so it remains on it's default of 'each line'. What we add though is a range operator that tests "am I currently within these two regular expressions" that's toggled `true` when you hit a "start" and `false` when you hit a blank line (assuming that's where you would want to stop?).

It applies the pattern transformation if this condition is true, and it ... ignores and carries on printing if it is not.

Comment: Awesome explanation, which really helps because I'm new to perl and it can do a number on my brain sometimes.

+ does not need to be escaped, and I don't believe using "&" to grab the matched string is valid in perl... but I could be wrong. So instead I used ()'s and $1 and It worked great! Finished a ~20 million line file in about 10 seconds

Comment: `perl` has a bad reputation, because it's really easy to make complicated and messy code snippets that are hard to understand. One liners don't generally help in my opinion - they're nice, but really you need to unpack them first, write them longhand, and pack it down again if you really need to.

Comment: Edited initial comment to included modifications to the solution

Comment: Also, this assumes that there will always be a blank line above "start: ", which is not always the case. I guess this could be corrected with this?

local $/ = "\n";

Comment: Won't work with a single line feed as a record separator, because that's per line, so you won't be including 'the rest' as part of 'the chunk'. I'll edit with an alternative.

Comment: @gkres121: The equivalent to `&` in the replacement string is to use the built-in variable `$&` which contains the whole matched string. You can use that if you wish, but the `\K` ("keep") metacharacter makes things much easier

Comment: Ah thanks for that - I had started googling because I knew it could be done, but "ampersand" isn't a particularly useful search term :)

Comment: Choosing this answer because of it's detailed description and quick and relevant edits. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest using `perl`. Although I would try to keep it in one-liner form:

```
perl -i -pe 'if ( /^start :/ .. /^$/){s/(modify [0-9]+ )/$1Append_DIR\//;s/(delete )/$1Append_DIR\//; }' file_to_edit
```

Or you can use redirection of stdout:

```
perl -pe 'if ( /^start :/ .. /^$/){s/(modify [0-9]+ )/$1Append_DIR\//;s/(delete )/$1Append_DIR\//; }' file_to_edit > new_file
```

Comment: Needs ()'s around "delete " in order to do the appending, and the escaped / after the directory:

perl -i -pe 'if ( /^start :/ .. /^$/){s/(modify [0-9]+ )/$1Append_DIR\//;s/(delete )/$1Append_DIR\//; }' file_to_edit

Works great! Editing a ~20 million line file in place took only ~20 seconds

Answer (score 0):

with gnu sed (with BRE syntax):

```
sed '/^start :[0-9][0-9]*$/{:a;n;/./{s/^\(modify [0-9][0-9]* \|delete \)/\1NewDir\//;ba}}' file.txt
```

The approach here is not to store the whole block and to proceed to the replacements. Here, when the start of the block is found the next line is loaded in pattern space, if the line is not empty, replacements are performed and the next line is loaded, etc. until the end of the block.

Note: gnu sed has the alternation feature `|` available, it may not be the case for some other sed versions.

a way with awk:

```
awk '/^start :[0-9]+$/,/^$/{if ($1=="modify"){$3="newdirMod/"$3;} else if ($1=="delete"){$2="newdirDel/"$2};}{print}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

sed's pattern ranges are your friend here:

```
sed -r '/^start :[0-9]+$/,/^$/ s/^(delete |modify [0-9]+ )/&prepended_dir\//' filename
```

The core of this trick is `/^start :[0-9]+$/,/^$/`, which is to be read as a condition under which the `s` command that follows it is executed. The condition is true if sed currently finds itself in  a range of lines of which the first matches the opening pattern `^start:[0-9]+$` and the last matches the closing pattern `^$` (an empty line). `-r` is for extended regex syntax (`-E` for old BSD seds), which makes the regex more pleasant to write.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple in Perl, and probably much faster than the sed equivalent

This one-line program inserts `Appended_DIR/` after any occurrence of `modify 999` or `delete` at the start of a line. It uses the range operator to restrict those changes to blocks of text starting with `start :999` and ending with a line containing no printable characters

```
perl -pe"s<^(?:modify\s+\d+|delete)\s+\K><Appended_DIR/> if /^start\s+:\d+$/ .. not /\S/" file_to_edit
```

Answer (score 0):

Good grief. sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. Once you start using constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) you are using the wrong tool. Just use awk:

```
awk '
    /^start :[0-9]+$/ { inBlock=1 }
    inBlock { sub(/^(modify [0-9]+|delete) /,"&Appended_DIR/") }
    /^$/ { inBlock=0 }
    { print }
' file
start :234
modify 123 Appended_DIR/directory1/directory2/file.txt
delete Appended_DIR/directory3/file2.txt
modify 899 Appended_DIR/directory4/file3.txt
```

There's various ways you can do the above in awk but I wrote it in the above style for clarity over brevity since I assume you aren't familiar with awk but should have no trouble following that since it reuses your own sed scripts regexps and replacement text.